# Is possible define a var at run-time and use it to access another var?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm not sure that this is possible.

I want to define a var at run-time and use it to access another var(defined in file,playbook..).

1. defined at run-time :

   ```
   typeConfig (possible values: "in_config" or "out_config")
   ```
2. defined in playbook:

   ```
   in_config:
     url_config: http://localhost/configuration

   out_config:
     url_config: http://config.pi.dyn-dns.org/configuration
   ```

I need to resolve something similar to this:

```
{{ {{ typeConfig }}.url_config }}
```

I try with:

```
- name: Mytest
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  sudo: yes
  vars:
    - in_config:
         url_config: http://localhost/configuration
    - out_config:
         url_config: http://config.pi.dyn-dns.org/configuration
  tasks:
     - set_fact:
          typeConfig: in_config
     - name: Value in_config.url_config
       debug: msg=" {{in_config.url_config}}"

     - name: Value out_config.url_config
       debug: msg=" {{out_config.url_config}}"

     - name: Value typeConfig
       debug: var=typeConfig

     - debug: msg="{{ {{ typeConfig }}.url_config }} "
```

ACTUAL RESULTS

> task path: /home/nor/gitrepos/iiot-iac/ansible/myUnitTest.yml:19
>   fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {
>       "failed": true, 
>       "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ {{ typeConfig }}.url_config }} " } " }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value using:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ vars[typeConfig].url_config }}"
```

---

Remember that `{{ ... }}` is not a way to write a variable name, but to start a Jinja2 expression. And when querying values, variables are referenced using Jinja2 expressions in Ansible, thus using `{{ {{ ... }} }}` makes no sense.